How can I mitigate water on a patio installed higher than pier and beam footing?
(Forgive all of ignorance and incorrect terminology, I have no idea what I am talking about.)
Pier and beam house, a concrete patio was installed directly abutting the back of the house by the previous owners, maybe 15-20 years ago. The area is the lowest point in the yard, and the concrete was poured up to and higher than and over the lowest layer of aluminum siding. There was a very small gap in places between the concrete and the siding, with no flashing or anything, creating a channel that funneled water directly into the vents in the band joist or whatever nearby. This led to a lot of water intrusion into the crawlspace and water damage to the sill plate and joists.
I had the concrete patio removed, and the wood sill plate and joists are being replaced. But the level of the soil is still just about level with the top of the concrete footing of the house. And this is the lowest point of the back yard. I do not think I can regrade  without causing damage to the roots of a massive oak tree in the yard.
How do I prevent future water intrusion? I see 3 options:

to extend the roof line with a covered patio beyond and covering that low region of the yard (where the existing stone walkway ends in the picture below), and route the water runoff to a better area of the yard. Extending the roof is prohibitively expensive though.

pour a new concrete patio, angled properly to divert water away from the house. The concrete would be higher than the footing, but I would remove the lowest layer of siding, have the concrete poured up to that level, and put flashing between the next layer and the concrete so that water rolls to the top surface of the patio and not in between the concrete and the wood band joist where the lowest layer of aluminum siding was removed.

regrade, french drains, try to get as low as possible. This is also difficult because there is not a really good option of where to divert the water to.


The main question is: is #2 above feasible, does it solve anything, or does it likely re-create the initial issue?
original patio

back wall now

The left of the door is slab I think, and the bottom level is the concrete and I think has enough clearance above the grade to be ok. To the right of the door you can see the vent which is above the sill plate that was just replaced.
The sandy area is where the concrete patio was. I think an extended roof over the red line area with concrete underneath would be ideal, but I think is unaffordable.
poorly drained area

This whole gravel area is above the footing and poorly drained, though there are catchment basins. When it rains this all floods into the vents into the crawlspace.
closer view of the height of the previous concrete

originally the patio was something like this

#2 idea, does this just end up with the same issue?

I am wondering if doing something like this makes sense, all along that back wall, removing all the gravel and landscaping.

dimensions of the back walls

Yeah, it's going to be hard to help from your vague description. Please show photos and provide dimensions, as in relative heights, etc. See [ask] and make sure you're asking a clear, specific question. We're not a discussion forum.

If the patio drains away from the house your 2nd sketch might work.  I think I'd still want to caulk.
